# How to obfuscate a xamarin App on VS 2019

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, obfuscation, xamarin.uwp

I need to protect the business logic on app and this is created with xamarin forms. I have searching information on forums and here about Babel and ConfuserEx but I don’t get it works.

**Case Babel**

I have installed demo SDK and I have updated the path on environment variables.
On Android Project I have added the following lines as I have seen on samples and book “*Xamarin Mobile Development for Android Cookbook*”

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="Babel" AssemblyName="Babel.Build, Version=9.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=138d17b5bd621ab7" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Babel InputFile="$(TargetPath)" OutputFile="$(TargetPath)" 
           VerboseLevel="5" 
           ObfuscateTypes="true" 
           ObfuscateEvents="true" 
           ObfuscateMethods="true" 
           ObfuscateProperties="true" 
           ObfuscateFields="true" 
           VirtualFunctions="true" 
           FlattenNamespaces="false" 
           UnicodeNormalization="false" 
           SuppressIldasm="true" 
           StringEncryption="xor" 
           ResourceEncryption="false" 
           ValueEncryption="false" 
           DynamicProxy="false" 
           ControlFlowObfuscation="goto=on" 
           ILIterations="5" />
    </Target>
```

The compilation is good, but I see dll with ILSpy tool and I can see flow, methods, variables, etc…

**Case ConfuserEx**

I have installed the VS Extension of ConfuserEx and I have tried to actívate it on common Project and it is obfuscated but When I archive in order to generate the apk, it isn’t obfuscated.
I have tried to do on Android Project instead common Project, but it don’t work.
Could you give me some advice in order to obfuscate app? I want to do it with Android, iOS and UWP app.
Because by default, uwp, droid and ios is easy to do reversing engineering, no?

Comment: have you tried using [DotFuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html) ? Also, ios AFAIK does not need obfuscation.  https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html

Comment: I read about it but I don't tried it because I have read that it is expensive and app is built for other business. Mmmm it seem that I have searched good, Why is not necessary for xamarin iOS?

Comment: Because iOS is AOT'd and IPA's are tough to reverse engineer anyway

Comment: Thank, Android is the weak link in the chain

Answer (score 2):

> Because by default, uwp, droid and ios is easy to do reversing
>   engineering, no?

Assuming that this is the question, the answer is that you are mostly wrong.

AOT compiled assemblies are not easy to reverse engineer, and AOT is mandatory for UWP and iOS, while on Android partial AOT is enabled now by the default and full AOT can be enabled too on the VS Enterprise.

Speaking of that there is nothing that can't be reverse engineered and you can still add the obfuscation on the top of AOT compilation to make it even more tough, just there is no built-in solution (and as far as I know no free solution either) so it is yours to pick the one that you like, such recommendations are not allowed here.

Comment: Thank you by the explication. UWP, i read Other thing but with your explication I have tried to decompile appxbundle and it is protected. Apple I known it, but I read that it had some problem and I tried to open the dll from ipa and I can read classes, global variables and methods, but flow is protected. 
About tools, some users said on forums that ConfuserEx works, others not, so this reason i tried with Babel that isn't free and I don't get to work it, and it support xamarin theoretically

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Babel with my Xamarin.Android apps for the last 3 years. It works extremely well. If you are having problems contact Alberto at Babel. He provides really great support. Most problems are because of the fact that the Xamarin's build process can vary from release to release and therefore you Babel task can require modifications to accommodate those changes

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to write. if I find solution, I will share here.